# Como gerar uma sub query em linq/EF

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, linq-to-sql

Olá, pessoal.

Tenho uma situação, onde concateno algumas sub querys SQLs que são concatenadas em outras consultas SQLs, para retornar alguns valores.

Tenho várias funções como estas, pois utilizo elas em várias outras consultas. Assim não preciso repetir código.

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer isso utilizando LinqSQL + EF.

Segue o exemplo de um código simples.

```
    public void Disponivel()
    {
        string query = "Select prod.Cod, prod.Descricao, ";
        query += QueryEstoqueDisponivel("prod.Cod") + " as EstoqueDiponivel ";
        query += " From TAB_Produtos prod ";

        //Aqui será gerado uma lista dos produtos...
    }


    public string QueryEstoqueDisponivel(string aliasProduto = "prod.Cod")
    {
        string query = "((Select Sum(est.Quantidade) " +
                       "  From ProdutoEstoque est " +
                       "   Where est.CodProdutos = " + aliasProduto +
                       " ) " +
                       " - (Select Sum(it.Quantidade) " +
                          " From PedidosItens it " +
                          " Where it.CodProdutos = " + aliasProduto + 
                          ")" +
                       ") ";

        return query;
    }
```

Comment: Só posso te dar uma dica, seu código é extramente inseguro. Repense isso.

Comment: O código acima, é apenas um exemplo que precisamos fazer com linq. Oque você quer dizer com inseguro?

Comment: Que até uma criança vai invadir o que quer que esteja fazendo aí.

Comment: Qual versão do C# você está usando? Você pode usar a interpolação de strings na query = $"" e vai passando os outros parametros, query = $"select * from {substring1} from {substring2}"

Comment: Conforme perguntei acima, necessito fazer em linq....

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando o EntityFramework, haverá no seu projeto uma classe de contexto para acesso ao banco de dados, e para cada tabela (TAB_Produtos, ProdutoEstoque e PedidosItens) haverá uma classe que a representa.

Provavelmente sua consulta ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
var lista = (from prod in contexto.TAB_Produtos 
             join est in contexto.ProdutoEstoque on prod.cod equals est.CodProduto
             join it in contexto.PedidosItens on prod.cod equals it.CodProduto
             group new 
             { 
                 CodProduto = prod.cod, 
                 Descricao = prod.Descricao,
                 QuantidadeEstoque = est.Quantidade, 
                 QuantidadePedidos = it.Quantidade 
             } 
             by new { prod.cod, prod.Descricao } 
             into g
             select new 
             {
                 CodProduto = g.key.cod,
                 Descricao = g.key.Descricao,
                 EstoqueDiponivel = g.Sum(ed => ed.QuantidadeEstoque) + g.Sum(ed.QuantidadePedidos)
             }).ToList();
```

Fique atento a sua construção de código SQL, pois o exemplo que apresentou está muito ruim. Estude este quesito, é importante.

Comment: Ja pensamos e fazer desta forma, porem em nosso sistema tem mais de 100 relatórios ou teste, que necessita saber o estoque disponível de um produto.
Como você fez  EstoqueDiponivel = g.Sum(ed => ed.QuantidadeEstoque) + g.Sum(ed.QuantidadePedidos), nós teríamos que repetir este comando em todos as chamadas.. Caso seja mudado algo no cálculo, terei que repassar o sistema inteiro..
Hoje mudamos apenas uma função e todo o sistema fica correto.
Por esto motivo gostaria de saber como fazer o mesmo exemplo em linq, sem soluções alternativas.

Comment: @FabianoRichetti você esta procurando a solução no lugar errado, o correto é vc separar isso e criar um serviço que faça a consulta do estoque e devolva um objeto com os dados. E nas views ou relatórios vc consome este serviço e o outro serviço de relatório e devolve um objeto da view especifica com a lista dinâmica formatada da forma que vc precisa. Fazer a interpolação igual vc quer fazer de sql com o entity não é o caminho. Outra maneira é executar o sql pelo entity e mapear para a lista de objetos necessária. Siga um desses caminhos.